# Why is the command startx not working on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

Tags: boot, startx

I have just flashed Raspbian to my 8 GB hard drive, but when I boot up the Raspberry Pi and log in, it says:

> bash: startx: command not found

Is there a problem with the boot files?

Comment: What OS did you install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have installed the Raspbian lite distribution, which is just command line, and no GUI. If you need a GUI, you could try installing Raspbian Pixel (full OS with GUI) on your SD card.

See this post for more discussion: [startx: command not found](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43847/startx-command-not-found)